# So viele Bezeichnungen für Nackedeis? (nackt, nackig, nackelig, nackert, nackend, …)

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Warum gibt es so viele Varianten von *nackt*? Bestehen bei *nackig*, *nackelig*, *nackert* und *nackend* Unterschiede in der Bedeutung, Herkunft oder Verwendung?

[In der Wikipedia heißt es](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nacktheit#Etymologie), es seien tabuistisch entstellte, verniedlichende oder verdeckende Wortvarianten.

Intuitiv würde ich die Varianten nur für nackte Kinder verwenden (Verniedlichung?). Ich habe mal mitbekommen, wie eine Krankenschwester einen circa 80-jährigen Patienten, der oben ohne herumlief, fragte: „Warum laufen Sie denn hier nackelig (nackelich) herum?“ Wenn sie das nicht belustigt betont hätte, hätte ich das als unpassend empfunden. Aber auch so wirkte das (wohl wegen der Verwendung von *nackelig*) auf mich eher wie eine Mutter, die mit ihrem Kind spricht.

Comment: *nackt* ist standardsprachlich; *nackig* regional nur bekannt; *nackend* veraltet, teils noch umgangssprachlich; und hätte *nackelig* nicht so viele Google Hits, würde ich behaupten, dass das Wort gar nicht existiert. Letztlich sind es einfach nur Synonyme.

Comment: Wie soll das Verdecken und »tabuistische Entstellen« funktionieren, wenn eh jeder bemerkt, was es mit dem Wort auf sich hat. Ganz zu schweigen davon, dass es diverse Ausdrücke gibt, die diese Aufgabe besser erfüllen, wie ein [Blick in einen Thesaurus](http://www.openthesaurus.de/synonyme/nackt) offenbart.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Wie viele Leute sagen _Scheibenkleister_, _A-Loch_, ...

Comment: Infantilisierende Behandlung Alter ist in der Pflege leider häufig, und das betrifft auch die Sprache.

Comment: Mir scheint, dass Du eine Antwort auf Deine Frage im zweiten Absatz nennst. Es wäre gut, wenn Du klarer machen könntest, was Du jetzt hier noch erwartest.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Ich stelle die Aussage in der Wikipedia in Frage, beziehungsweise möchte gerne wissen, ob das so stimmt (im Artikel sind dazu keine Quellen angegeben). Mich interessiert das Phänomen, wie aus einem Wort so viele so ähnliche Abwandlungen entstehen können – und ob das tatsächlich sein kann, dass die alle synonym sind und nicht doch einen (wenn auch kleinen) Bedeutungsunterschied haben.

Comment: Hmm... die Frage lässt sich eigentlich reduzieren auf "Warum gibt es Synonyme?" oder verstehe ich da etwas falsch?

Comment: Ich wäre ja durchaus dafür, die Frage umzuformulieren und neu zu eröffnen. Die Hauptfrage scheint mir zu sein, ob die Variationsvielfalt ungewöhnlich und am besten mit Hilfe des Tabus erklärbar ist oder ob es sich um ganz normale regionale Varianten handelt.

Comment: Für die Verniedlichungsthese spricht übrigens imho, dass der Fragesteller, wahrscheinlich absichtlich, das schöne Wort *Nackedei* im Titel verwandt hat.

Comment: `Nackert` kenne ich nur aus Bayern. `Nackelig` sehe ich auch zum ersten Mal.

Answer (score 3):

So blöd ist die Frage m.E. eigentlich nicht. Es geht ja im vorliegenden Fall nicht um irgendwelche Synonyme, sondern um nur geringfügige Abwandlungen des ursprünglichen Wortes. Wenn ich unor richtig verstehe, geht es ihm/ihr primär um den (tatsächlich ungeschickt formulierten und komplett unbelegten) Absatz im genannten [Wikipedia-Artikel](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nacktheit#Etymologie):

> Etymologie
>
> [...] Allerdings hat
>   sich dieses Wort in vielen Sprachen nicht ganz lautgesetzlich
>   entwickelt, offenbar wurde es tabuistisch entstellt. Solche
>   verniedlichenden oder verdeckenden Wortvarianten lassen sich in vielen
>   Sprachen, darunter im Deutschen, bis in die neueste Zeit verfolgen,
>   beispielsweise durch die umgangssprachlichen Formen „nackig“ oder
>   „nackend“ für „nackt“.

Die Kernaussage halte ich für durchaus nachvollziehbar: dass nämlich ein als tendenziell "unanständig" oder "grob" wahrgenommenes Wort entweder durch Synonyme ersetzt oder eben verniedlicht wird. Ähnliches gibt's ja im Englischen auch: *naked*, *nude*, *in the nuddy*, *starkers* (von *stark naked* für "splitternackt") etc. Vielleicht schmeißen wir einfach das "verdeckend" raus, dann ergibt das Ganze eigentlich schon Sinn.

Dass Verniedlichungen grundsätzlich eng mit der Kindersprache zusammenhängen (egal ob *von* oder *gegenüber* Kindern verwendet), liegt ja wohl ebenfalls auf der Hand. Typisch für solche Verniedlichungen scheint mir eine bewusste falsche Wortbildung zu sein ("*nack-ig", "*nacken-d": falsches Suffix bzw. falscher Wortstamm, um das Suffix zu erzwingen)

Im Gegensatz zu unor finde ich es relativ normal, wenn die entschärfende Verniedlichung nicht nur im Gespräch mit Kindern verwendet wird. Das genannte Beispiel aus der Altenpflege kann man zwar durchaus als herablassend interpretieren, meiner Meinung nach greift das aber zu kurz. Infantilisierende Sprache hat in diesem Bereich doch wohl auch den Zweck, eine gewisse menschliche Wärme zu suggerieren (mir fällt kein richtiges dt. Wort für *affectionate* ein, sorry). Gerade wenn die Pflegerin das "belustigt betont" spricht einiges dafür, dass sie eine potenziell peinliche Situation entschärfen will: Ohne entsprechende Betonung und mit dem direkteren "(halb-)nackt" klingt der Satz doch um einiges vorwurfsvoller, oder?

Lange Rede, kurzer Sinn: diese Varianten gibt es vermutlich in den meisten Sprachen, sie dienen dazu, Aussagen zu entschärfen oder (wahrgenommene) Tabuisierungen zu umschiffen. Dass es so viele gibt, liegt wohl einerseits an Regionalismen, aber u.U. auch daran, dass es meist eine ganze Reihe von falschen Bildungsmöglichkeiten gibt, von denen sich keine als "Standardverniedlichung" durchsetzen konnte.

Answer (score 2):

[Nackt](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GN02022) ist ein schönes Beispiel dafür, wie sich ein Wort aus seiner indoeuropäischen Wurzel weiterentwickelt.

Schon im Sanskrit gibt es **nagna**, das zum altslawischen **nagu** oder  dem lateinischen **nudus** wurde. So findet man diesen Wortstamm in seinen Varianten in allen indogermanischen Sprachen wieder - *naked/nude* auf Englisch oder eben *nackt, nackig, nackend, nackent, nackelig, etc.* im Deutschen. Diese Varianten sind eher auf regionale Verschiebungen im Dialekt als auf eine Verniedlichung zurückzuführen.

*"Nackt"* hat sich heute am meisten durchgesetzt, warum auch immer. Die anderen Varianten lassen sich aber regional durchaus noch finden.